# How to use variabels togehter with else if

Tags: javascript

I want to receive some data from this

```
<div id="past">
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-8">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-8">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-0">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-8">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-8">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
</div>
```

I only want to receive the number from the last div, for that i use

```
$('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;
```

then i want different things to happen when a specefic number is in that div

```
(function(){

var roll_history =  $('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;

if (roll_history = 0) {
console.log('green');
}
else if (roll_history = 1) {
console.log('red');
}
else if (roll_history = 2) {
console.log('red');
}
else if (roll_history = 3) {
console.log('red');
}
else if (roll_history = 4) {
console.log('red');
}
else if (roll_history = 5) {
console.log('red');
}
else if (roll_history = 6) {
console.log('red');
}
else if (roll_history = 7) {
console.log('red');
}
else if (roll_history = 8) {
 console.log('black');
}
else if (roll_history = 9) {
 console.log('black');
}
else if (roll_history = 10) {
 console.log('black');
}
else if (roll_history = 11) {
 console.log('black');
}
else if (roll_history = 12) {
 console.log('black');
}
else if (roll_history = 13) {
 console.log('black');
}
else if (roll_history = 14) {
 console.log('black');
}
setTimeout(arguments.callee, 35000);
})();
```

But the only output i get is "red"

I might gonna use something else than console.log later on.

Comment: Change `=` to `==` !

Comment: Isn't `textContent` always a string? @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy

Comment: = is assignment, == is comparison, in all those if and else if statements you're essentially trying to assign values to roll_history

Comment: @PeeHaa That is another problem too

Comment: here is a little tip: [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Comment: I mean that's a problem with your comment. @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy

Comment: By changing = to == it now only says black?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
(function(){

var roll_history =  $('#past')[0].childNodes[9].textContent;

console.log(roll_history)
if (roll_history == 0) {
console.log('green');
}
else if ((roll_history > 1) && (roll_history < 7)) {
console.log('red');
}
else if ((roll_history > 8) && (roll_history < 14)) {
console.log('black');
}
setTimeout(arguments.callee, 35000);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you need like this.Its match with last div

```js
(function(){

var roll_history =  parseInt($('#past').children('.ball').length);
console.log(roll_history)
if (roll_history == 0) {
console.log('green');
}
else if ((roll_history > 1) && (roll_history < 7)) {
console.log('red');
}
else if ((roll_history > 8) && (roll_history < 14)) {
 console.log('black');
}

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="past">
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-8">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-8">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-0">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-8">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-8">"number"</div>
  <div data-rollid="rollid" class="ball ball-1">"number"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only outputs 10 and black

Comment: ya its match the last div. then what you are  expecting? can you clarify?

Comment: It is because i want to log the outcome of a series of "rolls" and the data is logged in that way. I want it to log "green" if the roll is 0 and "red" if the roll is 1-7 and "black" if the roll is 8-14

Comment: It still only have the output 10 and black